# Benefits of JPMS/Project Jigsaw for Small Applications / Libraries

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I understand the benefits of the Java Platform Module System (JPMS) for large applications, but is there any reason to make a small library or application into a (single) module? If so, are [Modular Jar Files](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/doc/topics/modularjar.html) the best means of accomplishing this, or is the normal approach preferred?

Going forward, will there be performance implications for modularized v. classpath programs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Immediate performance implications include the following:

- Modularized applications can opt to use [jlink](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282) so that the distributable runtime is reduced in size: it only uses the modules you require. So if you don't need Swing, Corba, etc, it does not reside on disk. (more info [here](https://youtu.be/WJHjKMIrbD0?t=32m38s)).
- Modularized applications use the module graph for classloading; the algorithm for this is much faster than the linear search of classpath (more info [here](https://youtu.be/WJHjKMIrbD0?t=47m22s)).

This is by no means a guarantee that your app will be faster, but the above is undeniably attractive.

Longer term, consider this:

- Though experimental in JDK 9, there is an AOT compiler that (for Linux x64) will compile the `java.base` module to native code. This is likely the path forward for future Java releases. Surely this will improve startup time in the future. (again, more info [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJHjKMIrbD0&feature=youtu.be&t=32m38s))

Comment: Also in JDK 9 [compact strings](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) were introduced. Henceforth by default Java will use 1 byte per char for Latin characters. It does`t have connections with jigsaw project but might reduce your heap size and overall performance.

Comment: jlink can also be used by non-modularized applications, so this is not a benefit. Class loading speed gains are only relevant for the large JRE classes, so this is not a benefit either.

Answer (score 4):

> If so, are Modular Jar Files the best means of accomplishing this, or is the normal approach preferred?

I'm not sure what you you mean by "the normal approach" - [modular JARs](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-module-system-tutorial/#modules) are the "normal approach" to create artifacts that the module system will create a module for.

> [I]s there any reason to make a small library or application into a (single) module?

Yes, a few:

- Developers creating a modular application or using a modular library benefit from [reliable configuration](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-module-system-tutorial/#dependencies-readability), where they can only launch their application if all dependencies are present - this is a benefit no matter how large the application/library is.
- As a library designer you can hide internals. While [strong encapsulation](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-module-system-tutorial/#exports-accessibility) is only effective if your modular JAR is put onto the module path, the module descriptor still documents your intent in code, and allows you to more unscrupulously change your code. Application developers benefit as well because they can no longer accidentally depend on unsupported implementation details.
- Even in small applications and libraries, services might be used to decouple different aspects of functionality and make code more easily extensible.
- Only "real" modules (as opposed to automatic modules) can be included in a runtime image by `jlink`. Not providing a modular JAR robs your users of a library of that possibility.

Also note that you never know which small application or library might turn into something bigger. :)

> Going forward, will there be performance implications for modularized v. classpath programs?

While building the module graph and verifying modules costs time, the module system should make it up with an improved class loading strategy: It records for every package which module exports it and loads types from that package directly from that module instead of having to scan the entire class path. either way, I don't think this should be a deciding factor.

Answer (score 0):

Found this link informative
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2878952/java-platform/modularity-in-java-9.html

> **Aren't JAR files modular enough?**
>
> JAR files and the deployment environment in which they operate greatly
>   improve on the many legacy deployment conventions otherwise available.
>   But JAR files have no intrinsic uniqueness, apart from a rarely used
>   version number, which is hidden in a .jar manifest. The JAR file and
>   the optional manifest are not used as modularity conventions within
>   the Java runtime environment. So the package names of classes in the
>   file and their participation in a classpath are the only parts of the
>   JAR structure that lend modularity to the runtime environment.
>
> In short, JARs are a good attempt at modularization, but they don't
>   fulfill all the requirements for a truly modular environment.
>   Frameworks and platforms like Spring and OSGi use patterns and
>   enhancements to the JAR specification to provide environments for
>   building very capable and modular systems. Over time, however, even
>   these tools will succumb to a very unfortunate side-effect of the JAR
>   specification JAR hell!
>
> **Classpath/JAR hell**
>
> When the Java runtime environment allows for arbitrarily complex JAR
>   loading mechanisms, developers know they are in classpath hell or JAR
>   hell. A number of configurations can lead to this condition.
>
> First, consider a situation where a Java application developer
>   provides an updated version of the application and has packaged it in
>   a JAR file with the exact same name as the old version. The Java
>   runtime environment provides no validation facilities for determining
>   the correct JAR file. The runtime environment will simply load classes
>   from the JAR file that it finds first or that satisfies one of many
>   classpath rules. This leads to unexpected behavior at best.
>
> Another instance of JAR hell arises where two or more applications or
>   processes depend on different versions of a third-party library. Using
>   standard class-loading facilities, only one version of the third-party
>   library will be available at runtime, leading to errors in at least
>   one application or process.
>
> A full-featured and efficient Java module system should facilitate
>   separation of code into distinct, easily understood, and loosely
>   coupled modules. Dependencies should be clearly specified and strictly
>   enforced. Facilities should be available that allow modules to be
>   upgraded without having a negative effect on other modules. A modular
>   runtime environment should enable configurations that are specific to
>   a particular domain or vertical market, thus reducing the startup time
>   and system footprint of the environment.
>
> **Modularity solutions for Java**
>
> Along with the modularity features mentioned so far, recent efforts
>   add a few more. The following features are intended to optimize
>   performance and enable extending the runtime environment:
>
> **Segmented source code:** 
>   Source code separated into distinct, cached segments, each of which
>   contains a specific type of compiled code. The goals of which include
>   skipping non-method code during garbage sweeps, incremental builds,
>   and better memory management.
>
> **Build-time enforcements:**  Language constructs to enforce namespaces,
>   versioning, dependencies, and others.
>
> **Deployment facilities:** Support
>   for deploying scaled runtime environments according to specific needs,
>   such as those of a mobile device environment